# Tabs inside dialog box won't render

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I'm trying to initialize tabs inside of my dialog box but they don't work. The dialog box html is appended by initialization. I'm getting back the raw html. My code what I tried  out looks as it  follows.  However in firebug with breakpoints the code works

```
//HTML
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1">Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Send Email</a>
        </li>
    </ul>



    <div id="tab-1">

        <form action="#" method="post" id="edit_form"></form>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2">
        <div id="contact-wrapper">
            <form method="post" action="mailer.php" id="contactform"></form>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

and the Javascript

```
  // Init Dialog
        $('a.open_dialog').click(function() {
            $('#tabs').tabs();

            $('<div />').appendTo('body').load($(this).attr('href')).dialog({
                title: $(this).attr('title'),
                modal: true,
                draggable: false,
                width: 800,
                position: 'top',
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function() {
                        $.ajax({
                               type: "POST",
                               url: 'action.php',
                               data: $("#edit_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                               success: function(data)
                               {
                                   alert(data); // show response from the php script.
                               }
                             });

                    },
                    "Send Email": function() {

                        $.ajax({
                               type: "POST",
                               url: 'mailer.php',
                               data: $("#contactform").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                               success: function(data)
                               {
                                   alert(data); // show response from the php script.
                               }
                             });
                    }
                },
                close: function() {
                    location.reload(true);
                    allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );


                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to intialize your tabs after the dialog has opened.

```
$('<div />').dialog({
    open : function(){  //In case of autoOpen = true
      $('#tabs').tabs();
    }
});
```

If not, you can call sequentially call `.tabs()` after `.dialog()`

Comment: Your code seems to be okay but fires just if I put a break-point in firebug debugger  on $('#tabs').tabs();